# How to load images into a listView from a url?

Tags: c#

I need to load some pictures into a ListView. I've figured out how to do this with images stored on my local drive: when run, the code below displays exactly what I need.

```
private void getLocalImages()
{
    List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
    imageList.Add("C:\\....\\Pic1.png");
    imageList.Add("C:\\....\\Pic2.png");
    imageList.Add("C:\\....\\Pic3.png");
    
    ImageList imgl = new ImageList();
    imgl.ImageSize = new Size(200, 300);
    imgl.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
    {
        imgl.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(imageList[i]));
        listView1.Items.Add("", i);
    }

    listView1.LargeImageList = imgl;
}
```

How do I now modify this to load pictures stored on the web instead?

Edit: I'm using .NET Core 6.0, and this is a Windows Form application

Comment: please add more details: .NET version, UI framework (e.g. WPF, WinUI etc.).

Comment: Use `HttpClient`

Comment: There's no `ImageList` in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
private void getWebImages() 
{        
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
    imageList.Add("https://www. ... .com/.../Pic1.jpg");
    imageList.Add("https://www. ... .com/.../Pic1.jpg");
    imageList.Add("https://www. ... .com/.../Pic1.jpg");

    ImageList imgl = new ImageList();
    imgl.ImageSize = new Size(300, 200);
    imgl.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
    {
        Stream r = client.GetStreamAsync(imageList[i]).Result;
        imgl.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(r));
        listView1.Items.Add("", i);
    }

    listView1.LargeImageList = imgl;
            
}
```